# how to get certificate with public key in c++ out of pkcs12 container

Tags: c++, openssl

on *Ubuntu 14.04* with *openssl 1.0.1f* I create a certificate **with public key only** and put it into a pkcs#12 container.

In my c++ source I want to get the public key of the certificate and use *PKCS12_parse()* function.

Unfortunately - the *PKCS12_parse()* function returns the certificate only if a private key is also in the p12 file.
**Could someone please tell me how to get the public key in c++ source out of the certificate packet in a p12 file without transmitting the private key as well?**

```
Create a certificate in shell (password from stdin)
$ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.crt -sha256 -subj '/C=XX/ST=XXX/L=XXXX/O=XX/OU=XX/CN=XX' -passout stdin -days 1 -set_serial 0x123

If I create a PKCS12 container with private key as well, then it works
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.crt -inkey key.pem -passin stdin -passout stdin -out cert.p12 -name "test"

If I create a PKCS12 container with public key only (-nokeys)
$ openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -export -in cert.crt -inkey key.pem -passin stdin -passout stdin -out cert.p12 -name "test"
```

then it does not work. Here is the c++ source code to get the public key out of the certificate

```
X509 *cert;
EVP_PKEY *privateKey, *publicKey;

if(PKCS12_parse( p12, password, &privateKey, &cert, nullptr ))
{
    if(cert)
    {
        publicKey = X509_get_pubkey(cert);
    }
}
```

If I look into FileViewer, I see the public key.
[image]

So what does FileViewer to get the public key, and how can I do it with c++ and  openssl? Thanks.